# Choice to close the parent window when closing a child window

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a main window which opens a subwindow using:

```
this.Hide();
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
login = new frmLogin(this); 
login.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
login.Show();
```

This works good, the sub window is opened and if the user clicks the X button, both windows close.

There is a button in that window to do a task however, and if successful, must reopen the main window and close the sub window:

```
// main is reference to main window, this. is the sub window
main.ShowInTaskbar = true;
main.Show();
main.BringIntoView();
this.Close();
```

When this.close is called, the main window will close as well. I can't seem to separate it such that if the user clicks the X button, everything closes but if the user login successfully, the sub window is closed and the main window is unhidden. If I remove this line:

```
login.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
```

Then the login will work but if the user clicks the X button, the sub window closes but the main window is still rubbing in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in various way.

Without changing too much you can put a boolean property in your frmLogin, something like

```
public bool CloseMainForm { get; private set; }
```

Default value should be true, when you don't need to close your main window you can put it to False, like

```
...
main.BringIntoView();
this.CloseMainForm = false;
this.Close();
...
```

And change your event handler

```
login.Closed += (s, args) => { if (login.CloseMainForm) this.Close(); };
```